How can I raise Unbound's limit on local-zones in a view?
After upgrading from unbound 1.18 to 1.21, unbound has about a 10k-line limit on the number of local-zone directives in a view. How can I raise this limit to match the older version?
I upgraded a system from OpenBSD 7.5 to 7.6, which upgraded the bundled unbound from 1.18.1 to 1.21. The new version failed to start with the old configuration, which was about 76k lines long. (Mostly a long list of local-zone: "name" refuse zone directives in a view.)
~$ tail -4 unbound.conf
view: # censored DNS for all LAN clients
        name: "filter"
        view-first: yes
        include: "full-refuse_zones"
~$ unbound-checkconf unbound.conf
full-refuse_zones:9994: error: yacc stack overflow
read unbound.conf failed: 1 errors in configuration file
~$ wc unbound.conf full-refuse_zones
      82     168    1715 unbound.conf
   75987  227961 3196835 full-refuse_zones
   76069  228129 3198550 total

I double checked that the old version was loading the full configuration, and confirmed that 1.18 was not silently truncating, but correctly handling the entire config. On 1.21, while handling a view, it chokes just under 10k lines. If I move the long list of local-zones to the top level, just by adding a server: directive above the include, the file loads OK.
~$ tail -5 unbound-global.conf
view: # censored DNS for all LAN clients
        name: "filter"
        view-first: yes
server:
        include: "full-refuse_zones"
~$ unbound-checkconf unbound-global.conf
unbound-checkconf: no errors in unbound-global.conf
~$ wc unbound-global.conf full-refuse_zones
      83     169    1723 unbound-global.conf
   75987  227961 3196835 full-refuse_zones
   76070  228130 3198558 total

I haven't yet managed to find where yacc is throwing the error in either the NLnetLabs or OpenBSD versions of unbound, so I can't tell where it was changed. I haven't found a hint yet in man pages or release notes. If the change turns out to be a hard coded limit, I can build from source.
